# Set class to active on additional li elements upon navbar click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following side bar menu code. Upon click on any of the nav items it highlights / makes the class active.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li").click(function() {
    if ($(".nav li").removeClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

});


<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a data-target="#system-settings" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#system-settings" id="system-settings">System Settings</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#hosts" id="hosts" data-parent="#hosts">Hosts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#card-range" id="card-range">Cards</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pinpads" href="#pinpads">Printer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="xmls" href="#xmls">Pinpad</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Now I have similar items at the top of the page presented as a connected circle:

```
<div class="connected-line">
  <ul>
    <li class="active">1
      <p> System </p>
    </li>
    <li id="hosts">2
      <p> Hosts </p>
    </li>
    <li>3
      <p> Cards </p>
    </li>
    <li>4
      <p> Devices </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

See jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vk3qw09f/345/

Now if the user clicks on the side bar menu, it should also set corresponding  class as active on the "connected-line" list elements.

For eg: Cliking on navbar "System Settings" should also add a class 'active' to the li item inside the circled li "System"

I know it's not recommednded to have the same 2 ids on the same page. So looking for a smarter way to achieve this.

EDIT: my current code will only make that class active: `$(this).addClass("active");`

I probably want to make all classes that share the same name active

Comment: also your first `if()` should be `hasClass`, not `removeClass`

Comment: my current code will only make that class active: $(this).addClass("active"); I probably want to make all classes that share the same name active

Comment: @billy moat. how can i add class to a class. basically when i click on the sidebar menu, the corresponding circle list elements needs to have the active class

Comment: @Micheal check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is what you're looking for.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
    $(".connected-line li").removeClass("active");
    $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Full working snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/6nrvt2he/). Haven't added snippet in answer because:

a) SO doesn't yet support SCSS,
 b) i'm lazy.

Also note I made minor mods to your CSS and markup. Another note: duplicate `id`s are ***illegal*** in HTML. You have them? Expect your JavaScript to break. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code in your code. I hope, you can do it. Let me know, If any problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li a").click(function() {

      $(".connected-line ul li").removeClass("active");
       id = $(this).prop('id');
     $("#" + id).addClass("active")



  });

});




<div class="connected-line">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"  id="system-settings">1
      <p> System </p>
    </li>
    <li id="hosts">2
      <p> Hosts </p>
    </li>
    <li  id="card-range">3
      <p> Cards </p>
    </li>
    <li id="pinpads">4
      <p> Devices </p>
    </li>
    <li id="xmls" >5
      <p> Lanes </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a data-target="#system-settings" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#system-settings" id="system-settings">System Settings</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#hosts" id="hosts" data-parent="#hosts">Hosts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#card-range" id="card-range">Cards</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pinpads" href="#pinpads">Printer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="xmls" href="#xmls">Pinpad</a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: acoder..in your code you have 2 ids with 'id="system-settings". Is that not against css rules?

Comment: @Micheal check from here : http://www.jsfiddle.net/sultanul9/vk3qw09f/366

Answer (score 0):

It is best not you have two `elements` with the same `id` attribute.  This is because native functions such as `getElementById` will never be able to select the second instance of the element with that `id`.

That being said to get your demo to work I changed the js to use classes instead of ids on the second set of elements.  This can be achieved in many other ways as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li").click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    const clickedId = $(this).children()[0].id;
    $(`.${clickedId}`).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

and then in the html

```
<div class="connected-line">
  <ul>
    <li class="system-settings">1
      <p> System </p>
    </li>
    <li class="hosts">2
      <p> Hosts </p>
    </li>
    <li class="card-range">3
      <p> Cards </p>
    </li>
    <li class="pinpads">4
      <p> Devices </p>
    </li>
    <li class="xmls">5
      <p> Lanes </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a data-target="#system-settings" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#system-settings" id="system-settings">System Settings</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#hosts" id="hosts" data-parent="#hosts">Hosts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item ">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#card-range" id="card-range">Cards</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pinpads" href="#pinpads">Printer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="xmls" href="#xmls">Pinpad</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the html code as follows

```
<div class="connected-line">
  <ul>
    <li class="system active">1
      <p> System </p>
    </li>
    <li class="host" id="hosts">2
      <p> Hosts </p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">3
      <p> Cards </p>
    </li>
    <li class="device">4
      <p> Devices </p>
    </li>
    <li class="lane">5
      <p> Lanes </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item system">
    <a data-target="#system-settings" data-toggle="pill" class="nav-link" href="#system-settings" id="system-settings">System Settings</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item host">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#hosts" id="hosts" data-parent="#hosts">Hosts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item card">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#card-range" id="card-range">Cards</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item printer">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pinpads" href="#pinpads">Printer</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item pinpad">
    <a class="nav-link" id="xmls" href="#xmls">Pinpad</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Make sure to add same class name to matching li. Then modify the js code as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav li").click(function() {
 //Make sure to add class name immediately after "nav-item". For eg."nav-item printer"
  var calss=$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
  console.log(calss);
  $(".nav li").removeClass("active");
  $(".connected-line ul li").removeClass("active");
  $("li." + calss).addClass("active");
  });

});
```